# $p$ prime and $n$ primitive root. Show that there exists a $k$ such that $n^{k+1}\equiv n^k + 1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

Not really sure how to approach this one at all.

I tried

$$\begin{align}
n^{k+1} & \equiv n^k + 1 \pmod p \\
n^k \times n & \equiv n^k + 1 \pmod p \\
n^k \times n - n^k & \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
n^k \times (n - 1) & \equiv 1 \pmod p
\end{align}$$

but since $n$ is a primitive root, this means that $n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ but I can't really figure out what to do from here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: revise primitive roots.  The congruence $n^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ is true for all $n$ (except $0$): the fact that $n$ is a primitive root means much more than this.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. Just choose $k$ so that $n^k$ is the multiplicative inverse of $n-1$.